# Gulp, Pug - How do I compile all .pug files in subdirectories of src/ directory to /dist so they maintain the directory hierarchy?

Tags: html, gulp, pug

I have my `src/` directory as follows:

```
src/
---about/
------history.pug
------mission.pug
---contact/
------email.pug
---index.pug
```

I want my .pug files to be compiled in such a way that they maintain this directory hierarchy even in the `dist/` directory. Something like:

```
dist/
---about/
------history.html
------mission.html
---contact/
------email.html
---index.html
```

I'm using Gulp to process the pug files. Can this be achieved with one task using gulp, or otherwise? Thanks!

The Gulp task for handling my pug files:

```
gulp.task('pug', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/pug/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
        basedir: "./"
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/html'));
})
```

Comment: Yes, it can easily be achieved in one task.  You should show your code.

Comment: @Mark Edited the question to include my Gulp task. How can I incorporate it in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gulp.task('pug', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.pug')
   .pipe(pug())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})
```

will get your pug files and put them where I think you want.  In your code you have

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/html'));
```

but there is no html folder in your desired dist folder structure.  Same comment as to

```
gulp.src('src/pug/*.pug')
```

Your src directory does not have a pug subfolder, so why is src/pug here?

Also I don't think {basedir:....} is an option to the pug plugin so I removed it.

Comment: Woah thanks! That was simple enough. The src and dist directories i had shown in the question were just examples, not the real directories. I know I should've been more clear there. Oh, and basedir is an option. Double checked

Comment: Glad it worked.  If the answer was helpful, please accept it.  Thanks.